# How to parse html one time and get all css and html structor

Tags: android, algorithm

I'm writing an app as browser and need to parse html. My solution is I read one by one char and build page structor, example when I read `<div class="c10 c20">bold words</div>` then all words in div will paint with properties in class c10, c20, but the problem is div have two class with two place define as flowing:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.c10
{
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="c10 c20">bold words</div>
<style type="text/css">
.c20
{
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

So when I read to `<div` I dont know the properties of class c20 => I dont know save style for the div if I dont read to end of html. If I read to end of html for read all css then I have to read two times for one document. How to solve my problem?

Comment: You know the c20 properties because you read all the style before body.

Comment: c20 place in body, I think that method to solve the problem is read two times.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by not painting the div at the same time as you're parsing the HTML. Usually a browser will parse a web page into an internal data structure. After this data structure is built, it is processed by an rendering algorithm that "paints" the result to screen.

**An example demonstrating this approach with your example:**

*In this example we'll use a tree to represent the HTML and a hash map to store the CSS. This is not the best way to represent it, but it is simple to understand and visualize.*

1. Parse the HTML. When the parser reads a HTML element, put it into the tree, and when the parser reads a CSS-class, store it in the hash map.
2. Traverse the tree with the rendering algorithm. When the rendering algorithm finds the div referencing the CSS-class c10 and c20, simply look up the corresponding CSS properties in the hash map to determine how it should be painted to the screen.

**After parsing the tree and hash map would look something like this:**

```
Tree (omitting style-elements)
------------------------------
html
|-- head
|-- body
    |-- div class="c10 c20"

Hash map
--------
 key -> value
.c10 -> font-size:10px
.c20 -> font-size:20px
```

This way the HTML-file is only read once, but all CSS-styles is available to the rendering algorithm. You're still, in a sense, "reading" the HTML twice, but the cost of traversing a data structure in memory is dwarfed by the cost of reading from the file.

If you're not the type that really likes to implement every last line of code in your application (that is also fine, and sometimes very fun, although a bit time consuming) you'll probably be able to find a library that does HTML parsing into an object structure. Then you only have to make the rendering-algorithm. I would also suggest that you read up on the [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM).

Comment: If I use DOM, `<div class="c10 c20">in div<p>intersect</p>asdf</div>` then text of the div is **in div intersect asdf**. How to get text of div is **in div** and **asdf**

Comment: You would use is something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), or any other Java HTML parser (I guess you'll need it to be Java to get it to work with android). To get the content of the div afther parsing the HTML, you would first [select it](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). Check out [try jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/~IkjlKJMEdF7VRpsb-UPWjgxE6d8) for an interactive example of how to select your div. Then you would call [.Text()](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) on the selected div to get the text inside the div.

Comment: does jsoup support not well form xml?

Comment: I don't know, but you could probably find out by using the try jsoup page, or reading the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)